# Why prefer distributing a shared library with executables instead of linking statically?

Tags: windows, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Scenario: two unrelated pieces of software are going to be distributed with their own copy of the same shared library. They will both be installed on the same machine (running Windows), and they're going to be run at the same time.

In this scenario - from my understanding, the two programs won't share the library in memory without somehow specifying it - which doesn't seem to be the norm (correct me if I'm wrong)... In other words, most or all of the programs that use this library will have their own copy of it, both in memory and on disk, which is the same as what statically linked programs would have - roughly speaking.

Is it preferable for the writers of each program to ship the shared library (together with their programs) over linking with the library statically, or is the difference negligible?

Comment: Please specify the operating system(s) you have in mind. On Linux,
competently packaged software does not distribute copies of its third party
dependencies. It expresses the dependency in the package, and the package
manager will only install a single copy of a library to satisfy all of its
clients.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't fully aware of that. I've mostly only seen that scenario on Windows. Edited the question.